# Convert a css color to 16-bit rgb

Tags: applescript, hex

I'm trying to convert a css hex color like `129a8f` into a format suitable for `choose color default color xxx` (in this case, `{4626, 39578, 36751}`). I've got ruby code that does the trick

```
if m = input.match('([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})') then
  clr = "{#{m[1].hex*257}, #{m[2].hex*257}, #{m[3].hex*257}}"
```

and now I need the same in AppleScript (which I don't know ;). Any pointers?

Comment: The Algo is simple - break the hex string into pairs of 2 each - `129a8f` gives `12 9a 8f` representing R, G and B respectively. Converting each of these hex to equivalent integer will give you the required result. Now you can implement in whatever language you like.

Comment: @AshisKumarSahoo: thanks, but my question is about Applescript specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ruby` in AppleScript script.

```
set x to text returned of (display dialog "Type a css hex color." default answer "129a8f")
set xx to do shell script "/usr/bin/env ruby -e  'x=\"" & x & "\"; if m= x.match(\"([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})\") then puts \"{#{m[1].hex*257}, #{m[2].hex*257}, #{m[3].hex*257}}\"; end' "
if xx is "" then
    display alert x & " is not a valid css hex color" buttons {"OK"} cancel button "OK"
else
    set xxx to run script xx -- convert ruby string to AppleScript list
    set newColor to choose color default color xxx
end if
```

--

Or an AppleScript script without ruby

```
property hexChrs : "0123456789abcdef"

set x to text returned of (display dialog "Type a css hex color." default answer "129a8f")
set xxx to my cssHexColor_To_RGBColor(x)
set newColor to choose color default color xxx

on cssHexColor_To_RGBColor(h) -- convert 
    if (count h) < 6 then my badColor(h)
    set astid to text item delimiters
    set rgbColor to {}
    try
        repeat with i from 1 to 6 by 2
            set end of rgbColor to ((my getHexVal(text i of h)) * 16 + (my getHexVal(text (i + 1) of h))) * 257
        end repeat
    end try
    set text item delimiters to astid
    if (count rgbColor) < 3 then my badColor(h)
    return rgbColor
end cssHexColor_To_RGBColor

on getHexVal(c)
    if c is not in hexChrs then error
    set text item delimiters to c
    return (count text item 1 of hexChrs)
end getHexVal

on badColor(n)
    display alert n & " is not a valid css hex color" buttons {"OK"} cancel button "OK"
end badColor
```